# Node Aggregate Log

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i am looking to get a simple random sample using Node.

In the console it works with `db.commands.aggregate({$sample: { size: 1 }})`

But when i `console.log` the result using Node it returns an AggregationCursor object.

```
commands.aggregate( [{ $sample: { size: 1 } }], function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    client.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently aggregate returns an array, and can be iterated using `forEach`.

This was the solution that worked for me, ultimately returning the single document as an Object.

```
commands.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }])
    .forEach((doc) => {console.log(doc)} , 
        (err) => {console.log(err);}
);
```